# How to know if udev or mdev is enabled

Tags: linux, spi, udev

I have a device connected to the spi bus of the process, but it is not shown in /dev/. The spi device driver should create the node automatically. So I want to check if udev or mdev is enabled in my system. Can anyone tell me how to check?

I don't see udev or mdev in /sbin, or /bin. Does this mean something?

Thanks!

Comment: use "udevadm monitor" or "udevd" commands , for logs on inserting and extracting SPI device to your system.get the logs and analysis those logs can make your help

Comment: Thanks. The device is not hot pluggable, so I cannot unplug and replug it to see the logs. Is there any other way of checking if udev or mdev is working?

Answer (score 2):

To check whether mdev is working or not , First check in /sbin/ whether mdev is present or not. If it is not present then probably mdev is not configured properly, or else if it is present then check whether hotplug handler has been set properly.
i.e inside /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug it should be /sbin/mdev written.

If it is also correct that means you have proper configuration of mdev inside your system.
Above description is only for mdev, for udev you can check the process list using ps -e 
check whether udevd --daemon is running or not by checking the list of processes.

For more details you can check the below links:

http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/hotplug/

http://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/docs/mdev.txt